# Scale all images on mobile / tablet

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make every image and video on my site scale to fit tablet / mobile.

The solution I've tried is the viewport meta tag:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  
  img {
    width: 50%;
  } 
}
```

But without results. I cannot seem to achieve this with bootstrap img-fluid class, as the website has many layered images, horizontal and vertical scrolling, and an ancient javascript applied to make the images draggable on desktop.

In such a case, is the viewport media tag the best option, and any ideas of why it wouldn't function?

The Javascript I am using is to make images draggable by the visitor.

Comment: 320px is quite small. I don't even know if there is devices with that small screen nowadays. Use devtools and enable mobile preview, then adjust screen to 319px, see if it really does not work.

Comment: Also please provide sample code as now it should be working fine (if you have viewport meta tag set)

Comment: Oh, good point! I changed the size to 500px and this worked perfectly for some of my images (the ones without javascript rule applied). However, those with javascript rule applied are still failing to re-size.

Comment: @Justinas iPhone 5 and iPhone SE have 320px screens.